# Visual Studio 2008 Test Run taking long to Complete

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mstest

I have a bunch of test projects in my solution. Most of them run instantly and finish instantly. One however takes a long time to complete. The actual tests run fast, but for a long period after all the tests have passed the interface still says "Test Run Completing...". The test run eventually finishes after 10-20 seconds. Has anyone experiences this problem or have any idea what particular aspect of code might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a long-running Teardown (in NUnit, TestFixtureTearDown - not sure if it's exactly the same in mstest)? That would run after all tests have finished and could doing some time-intensive clean up. That would explain why all tests have passed by it still appears to be doing something and would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: That put me on the right track. Seems something was holding onto resources for a extended period of time. Normal destructors were never being called, so I ended up needing to make several classes derive IDisposable and calling the dispose myself.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a disc I/O problem. The test run will write the results to a number of files. Have you configured these to be on a slow / hard to reach drive?

Comment: Nope. The other test projects that complete instantly have equal number of tests with comparable volumes of test results are ending up on the same drive.